# Group by options in original order does not groups the records in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Group by options in ascending order (or) in descending order in crystal reports groups the records fine. But Group by options in original order does not groups the records in crystal reports.
       **If I summarize the fields with Group by options in original order ..., instead of summarize..., the stupid crystal reports just shows all the records.** If I summarize the fields with Group by options in ascending order/in descending order, it summarize the records fine. Anyone has solution... please share it to me.

Answer (score -1):

The issue I see here is crystal reports is grouping the report with the order it is getting from database since you used `Group by original order`.  here data is grouped as it is obtained from database.

I would suggest you to go for `ascending` or `descending` as it is more organized way

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need original order only. In stored procedure itself I have sorted the records. The sorting is based on another three fields.